# java bytebuffer write read append

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm trying to use ByteBuffer to parse a stream of data packets which I receive as byte arrays and may contain partial or multiple packets. The packets are of variable length so I need to parse the first two bytes to get the packet length and it seems that once I flip() the buffer to read the packet I cannot go back and append more data if the packet is not complete.

How can I write data to the buffer, read some of it to verify the contents and then append more data to it if necessary while preserving the read data?

```
class Foo {

    static final byte[] DATA1 = {0, 13, 2, 65, 88, 80, 55, 51, 52, 84, 82, 43, -111};
    static final byte[] DATA2 = {0, 21, 6, 2, 3, 67, 23, 71, -77, 24, -66, -12, -76, 98, 25, 61, 54, -20, 127, -118, 71};
    static final byte[] DATA3 = {0, 21, 5, 3, 5, 67};
    static final byte[] DATA4 = {23, 72, -50, 24, -66, -9, -31, -86, 25, 61, -95, 75, 71, 47, -102, 0, 13, 2, 84};
    static final byte[] DATA5 = {82, 65, 28, 10, 65, 71, 52, 44, 11};

    ByteBuffer mByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);

    public void test() {
        mByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        parse(DATA1);
        parse(DATA2);
        parse(DATA3);
        parse(DATA4);
        parse(DATA5);
    }

    public void parse(byte[] bytes) {
        short byteCount;
        short crc;

        mByteBuffer.put(bytes);
        mByteBuffer.flip();

        while (mByteBuffer.remaining() > 5) {
            byteCount = mByteBuffer.getShort();

            // check for invalid buffer
            if (byteCount < 5) {
                mByteBuffer.clear();
                return;
            }

            if (mByteBuffer.remaining() < (byteCount - 2)) {
                // TODO: incomplete packet, do something
            }

            // payload (u8[1 .. 4092])
            byte[] payload = new byte[byteCount - 4];
            mByteBuffer.get(payload, 0, payload.length);

            // crc (u16)
            crc = mByteBuffer.getShort();
        }

        mByteBuffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `compact()` after the `getShort()`, or in general after any sequence of gets or writes and before the next `read()`.

Comment: won't `compact()` remove any data that I've already read, like the byte count I'm peeking at to see if I have a complete packet or not?